# Is a global variable the only way to return the built AST in bison?

Tags: parsing, global-variables, bison, abstract-syntax-tree

To return the fully built AST, I was told I should use a global variable in which I store it:

```
%{

AST::Root* root;

%}

%start program

%%

program:
    ...            { $$ = root = new AST::Root(...) }
    ...
    ;
```

But is this the only way? Or is there a better way, maybe a way to return the AST directly from `yyparse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%parse-param` for adding additional parameters to `yyparse()`. There is [descrition](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Parser-Function.html)